# Regex Pattern to match random string of characters between sentence

Tags: regex

I want to match the following string of characters:

```
2017-03-17 07:33:17|ERROR|response|SOAP|validation|client|<IP_ADDR>|504021500931703170733169658002||<5_digit_figure>|A service error occurred. Maybe http message illegal or analyse failed!|<5_digit_figure>|OA:,DA:<7_digit_number>|2017-03-17 07:33:17|
```

The part which I want to match is this:

*A service error occurred. Maybe http message illegal or analyse failed!*.

It can be anything, as it contains the detailed error message, including special characters, and doesn't have any specific length. Then it is also followed by other characters which I can match. I have been able to match up to the '60027' section, but I have difficulty capturing the random characters without the use of the '.*' regex as it captures everything after that. Any ideas?

Comment: `.*?` the `?` makes it "lazy".

Comment: should the matched part always contain `error` word?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no it doesn't have to contain the word

Comment: @zer00ne yap, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: @PeterM your'e very welcome, sir. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's the 11th field:

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){10}([^|]*)
```

The target input will be in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is an overkill here. Why not just split the string by '|', then extract the 11th sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

@zer00ne's answer did it, using (.*?)\| helped me match up to the next '|' character. Thanks all of you!